# Getting img src in code behind vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have  two different types of image tags in asp.net as such

```
<asp:Image ID="ADimage1"    height="150"  width="150"  src="../img/ProfilePic.png"     
runat="server" />
```

'binary data as image has been set

```
<asp:Image ID="ADimage2"    height="150"  width="150"  src="data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGg"   runat="server" />
```

and a vb.net button click as such

```
  Protected Sub btnUploadClick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles     btnUpload.Click
    'not able to get image url
    Dim imageurl1 As String =ADimage1.ImageUrl

    'not able to get image url
    Dim imageurl2 As String =ADimage2.ImageUrl
 EndSub
```

I am not able to get image url in the backend. it is vb.net web application . Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `ImageUrl` attribure in `<asp:Image />` tag, then you will get it by `ADimage1.ImageUrl`. Use `ImageUrl` instead of `src`, as

```
<asp:Image ID="ADimage1" height="150" width="150" ImageUrl="../img/ProfilePic.png" runat="server" />
```

**OR**

Of you want to use `src` only then do the following to get `src` value,

```
Dim imageurl1 As String = ADimage1.Attributes("src").ToString()

Dim imageurl2 As String = ADimage2.Attributes("src").ToString()
```

Comment: Bharadwaj i am getting attributes count as 0 while debugging

Comment: Imageurl can't be used in my case. I use to url  for both setting and getting as such . Setting in code behind:  ADimage1.ImageUrl = "../img/domailProfilePic.png"   which works fine . when I inspect html element it is finally rendered to src in browser. The same src i should get when i submit.

Comment: I was able to get imageurl when i directly wrote in aspx page. I order to acheive it I coded such a way that, before actual submit i called onclientclick javascript where i tried taking the src content and add to imageUrl and go to submit . That also didn't work

Comment: Since it is server control, it is rendered as img in client side. ImageUrl will be as src attribute. If you want to access the url content then you have to use "ImageUrl" from the codebehind and "src" from client script.

Comment: Ya When the use ImageUrl in code behind i am getting empty

Comment: You have to set "ImageUrl" attribute in the html of the tag. Then you can get it in codebehind. The same "ImageUrl" will be rendered as "src" at client side. No need to add "src" for that.

Comment: Bharadwaj . Can you let me know how can i add add and set ImageUrl attribute using jquery. Since on first page load I am calling web service to get image in byte array and setting to the image src. If you let me  know setting to the imageUrl attribute that would be great.

Comment: In this case I will suggest you to try using html img tag with 'runat="server"'.  don't use Asp.net Image tag. So you can set "src" direct from jquery and you can access "src" from codebehind through attributes.

Comment: Tried it , it is not taking the src set from jquery but only take what values was in initial page load

Comment: How are you trying in jquery?

Comment: Try $("[id$='img_id']").attr("src",url);